# Deprecated Functionality: rawurlencode(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($string) of type string is deprecated s

Tags: magento-upgrade, setup-upgrade, magento2-enterprise, magento2.4.5p1

I upgraded the magento version from 2.3.6-p1 to 2.4.5-p1 enterprise edition.

When I run bin/magento setup:upgrade command throws following error.

Deprecated Functionality: rawurlencode(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($string) of type string is deprecated in /var/www/html/vendor/fastly/magento2/Model/Api.php on line 143

Please guide me to solve this.
My PHP version is 8.1

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the `fastly_service_id` set in config to avoid the error. Or you can add patch to make the `getServiceId` to always return string.

See issue in github https://github.com/fastly/fastly-magento2/issues/612